# How can I initialization a massive of static class in c++

Tags: c++

I have header.h

```
Class A
{
int var_1;
int var_2; 
};
Class b
{
private: static A var[MAX];
.....
};
```

But how can I initialize this property in header.cpp?

Comment: Properly? Have you got anything improper to start us of with?

Comment: And what kind of naming is "header.cpp"?!

Answer (score 3):

Give A a default constructor that sets the ints to 0s or something.

`A b::var[MAX] = {};`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is `class A` with the public constructor that takes no arguments (or default constructor):

File *b.h* :

```
#include "a.h"

// global constant:
const int MAX = 10;

class B {
private:
    static A var[MAX];    // declaration
};
```

File *b.cpp* :

```
#include "b.h"

A B::var[MAX] = {};       // definition
```

Answer (score 0):

In implementation file:

```
A b::var[] = {}; // static member definition
                 // A() is called for each member so you might want
                 // to implement it
```

example:

```
#define MAX 10

class A
{
    int var_1;
    int var_2; 
};
class b
{
private: 
    static A var[MAX];   // static member declaration
};

A b::var[] = {};         // static member definition

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ndkPmX